# Google Chrome does not sync passwords

Tags: login, google-chrome, password, sync

I have a problem with syncing passwords with Google Chrome.

Whenever I save a password in Chrome, it just saves it locally. If I have previously saved the password on Google password manager in the cloud it doesn't show up!

The problem is syncing, not saving or suggest saving passwords locally. And yes I turned sync all data ON.

By the way, this problem showed up after I forgot my Linux(Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) password and tried to reset it so I deleted some files like:

```
login.keyring
user.keystore
in .local/share/keyrings
```

I tried on a Windows operating system that I'm using and google synced my password on the cloud! so definitely, it's the Ubuntu.

also reinstalled Google Chrome with these commands and didn't work:

```
sudo apt remove google-chrome-stable
```

or

```
sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable
```

then

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try removing Google Chrome with:

```
sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable
```

Then:

```
sudo chown -Rc $USER:$USER $HOME
```

Finally:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
sudo rm -rf ~/.cache
```

Comment: Worked for me on Linux Mint 18

Comment: I have `Lubuntu` with `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS` from `lsb_release -a` and cannot find `google-chrome-stable` but `chromium` in the apt sources. It does not sync. What can I do?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem in Linux Ubuntu.
This will solve your problem if you are able to view saved password at password.google.com.

1. `cd ~/.config`
2. `mv google-chrome google-chrome-old`
3. Re launch chrome
4. Sign in with your account again and sync it.

Comment: This solution worked for me on ubuntu 20

Comment: This solution worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This solution worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 4):

There is simple option to resolve this issue:

1. Open [chrome://settings](https://chrome://settings).
2. Press "You and Google", "Turn off" and popup appears.
3. Turn "Clear bookmarks, history, passwords..." on, fix won't work without this checkbox.
4. Reopen google chrome.
5. Sign in and enable sync.

Comment: This did solve the problem for me. It caused me to lose all of my extension settings. These don't seem to by synched to google. I wish we understood the underlying cause and could apply a more direct fix to the problem so it doesn't happen in the future. Any debug techniques for next time?